# EXC_??? (11) (code=0, subcode=0x0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm newbie here and iphone app dev.
Sometimes I see this error & app crash on running my app by simulator.
xcode 4.4.1 , Mountain Lion, iOS 5.1 used.

I guess it's running time dependent error because it occurs after running the app a few sec(over 30s) later.
How can I detect and fix this?

thank you for your attention.

hm..I can't upload my capture image

Thread 1

0 0x0eae45e6

7 glDrawElements

8 -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads..

9 -[CCTextureAtlas drawQuads]

10 -[CCSpriteBatchNode draw]

11 -[CCTMXLayer draw]

12 -[CCSpriteBatchNode visit]

13 -[CCNode visit]

14 -[CCNode visit]

15 -[CCNode visit]

16 -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene]

17 -[CCDirectorDisplayLink mainLoop:]

18 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(...

27 UIApplicationMain

28 main

29 start

**editor window error**

0xeae45e6: movaps %xmm4, -2472(%ebp)   <<<<<

> Thread 1: EXC_???(11)(code=0, subcode=0x0)

0xeae45ed: movaps 64(%edi), %xmm4

0xeae45f1: movaps %xmm4, %xmm5

0xeae45f4: mulps %xmm1, %xmm5

0xeae45f7: addps 64(%eax), %xmm5

0xeae45fb: movaps %xmm5, -2456(%ebp)

0xeae4602: movaps %xmm5, %xmm6

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking - maybe post some code samples if you want a good answer

Comment: Thanks for comment. this is all hint that I can take. I don't know which code is responsible to this. There is no console error log.

Comment: if (odd error) { [self reboot]; } … first thing I'd try here. Then start from scratch with a new project to see if this is a general issue, or specific to a certain project. In the latter case it's probably a code bug.

Comment: are you releasing all of your sprites that "fall off the screen"?

Comment: I've come across this issue, but only during debugging. And I'm able to continue without any apparent consequences. Are you able to also continue the debugger at the point of this break?

Comment: I too only have the problem when debugging, and am able to continue after the exception...

Comment: It's a funny exception, especially since you can click CONTINUE in XCode to no apparent ill effect (program continues as normal) (at least when occurs in simulator)

Comment: I also see this issue, continue works for me! I'm walking through a complex node-based tree structure and it'll happen randomly.

Comment: same problem happens with me... what objects you are drawing .. i'm using a tmx map

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's a memory problem:

1. Somewhere in your code you could be corrupting memory - check those places where you access arrays (for out of bounds reading), create formatted strings, release objects.
2. Try using instruments and check memory - maybe you are leaking it very quickly somewhere else.

Comment: I thought first it should be problem about memory leak. But the error EXC_??? occurs even though no memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this exact EXC_??? (11) error pretty consistently.

In my case it was multithreading coding error - one of the class members accessed on one thread was also modified (init... release...) by another thread. This means that the code was accessing an instance that was already released or completely recreated.

So adding @synchronized where applicable fixed the error.

Comment: I haven't use any multithread code(NSThread,NSOperation), but found some hint about returning objects of methods. amen is member variable, -(CCArray*)A { amen = [CCArray array]; ... [amen addObject:obj]; .... return amen; } -(void)B { CCArray *bmen = [self A];  ... //code using bmen }  Is this responsible to multithread error?

Comment: Though changed some code to 'CCArray *bmen = [[CCArray alloc] initWithArray:[self A]];'  EXC_??? (11) error is still annoying me

Answer (score 1):

Goto **CCDirector** or, **CCDirectoriOS** whichever you are using.. and just add

```
@implementation CCDirectorDisplayLink


-(void) mainLoop:(id)sender
{
   if(displayLink_)//Crash fix
      [self drawScene];
}
```

It should fix the crash..

Answer (score 0):

This error was cause by having the app installed via other ways other than via xcode and then trying to run using xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly suspect** this exception gets raised when you **forget to disable vertex attributes that are not part of the current shader**.

Try running this function:

```
  // debug
  static void PrintAllActiveAttributes()
  {
    int maxAttribs ;
    glGetIntegerv( GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &maxAttribs ) ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < maxAttribs ; i++ )
    {
      int enabled ;
      glGetVertexAttribiv( i, GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ENABLED, &enabled ) ;
      if( enabled )  printf( "INDEX %d ENABLED\n", i ) ;
    }
  }
```

If you **did not** disable some attributes (by calling `glDisableVertexAttribArray`) that were used by a previously bound shader, then **those attributes will still be active**, even if the currently bound vertex buffer does not use it.  I believe this results in some memory OOB exceptions being thrown.